# Mounting a new resolv.conf file to a deployment

Tags: containers, kubernetes

I am been trying to mount a resolv.conf file that my service uses `option ndots = 5` with `option ndots = 1`, following an issue with slow kube-dns resolution times. 
The problem is after I apply the yaml file the volumes are not getting mounted onto the deployment. 
`kubectl describe deploy/<deployment-name>` returned

```
 Mounts:                <none>
  Volumes:                <none>
```

I tried deleting the deployment/service but nothing works.

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/35525#issuecomment-257919311

Comment: Have you tried mounting a ConfigMap with the `resolv.conf`?

Answer (score 0):

Just putting it here for future reference:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/33554#issuecomment-251870060

This solved by problem. The issue was yaml formatting if really flaky, make sure it matches the example shown in the example of the link.